# Adding text before and after cart contents block in Drupal 7 commerce

Tags: commerce

I need to add some text above and below the Cart Contents block at the top of the checkout form. I tried just editing the view and adding a header and footer to that view but no dice, it doesn't work (it shows in the View preview but not in the view results when saved).

So I'm looking for the page--checkout.tpl.php form and I can't find it anywhere. Does anyone know where I can find this template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this, for me, is by code, as checkout pages are normal Drupal forms and as such, we can use hook_form_alter() to do whatever we need. In this case, you can use

```
(yourmoduleorthemename)_form_commerce_checkout_form_checkout_alter (&$form, &$form_state)
```

And inside it, you can use Form API(https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7#markup-attribute) to change the way you want.

You can also create a block and put on the "checkout/%/*", but it generates a lot of extra markup for almost nothing.

I believe you can solve your problem with one of these, but let me know if you need more details.

Comment: yea, I've put everything in a module using the alter form you mentioned. That allows me to use the #description setting to put content before and the #suffix setting to put content after. Thanks for your help!